# Dance with Dragons: Margaery Tyrell vs. Mance Rayder

Tags: expansions, game-of-thrones

In the Dance with Dragons expansion, the house card for Margaery Tyrell reads "If you are defending your home or a territory that has power token on it, the final combat strength of your opponent is 2". The house card for Mance Rayder reads "Your final combat strength is equal to the wildling threat".

What happens when these two cards are played against each other? How is the final strength of the Baratheon player resolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Baratheon strength 2 is Final if the Throne ranking so determines : 
which house executes first and next house executes after. So slightly counter-intuitively the lower Throne ranking would receive the benefit in this case.

http://community.fantasyflightgames.com/index.php?/topic/73198-house-card-questions/
http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/867434/final-combat-strength